# How to keep an excel database that imports data from internet updated?

Tags: database, google-sheets, import, hyperlink, auto-update

In google sheets, I do have links and I manually import data from an specific public server using the command IMPORT(). I just have to press restart bottom.

How can run the process automatically every day? and generate a report every day?

Comment: what is the structure of the informations located in the server ?

Answer (score 0):

You can put a daily trigger on

```
function importData(){
  // source
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('fileId'); 
  var data = ss.getSheetByName('sheetName').getDataRange().getValues()

  // destination
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('destSheetName')
  sh.getRange(1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data)
}
```